# How to assign people or group field to current user with javascript

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, development

I have a list field named `PersoniKonfirmues` and I want this field to be set to the current user that is logged in. I want to do this with client side using javascript in Sharepoint 2013

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below code in `Script Editor WebPart` in your NewForm

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Wait until SP.JS has loaded before calling getWebUserData 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(SetCurrentUsernameToPeoplePicker, "sp.js");
});

function SetCurrentUsernameToPeoplePicker()
{
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.website = ctx.get_web();
this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
ctx.load(currentUser);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSucceess), 
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));
}

function onSucceess(sender, args)
 {
var loginName = currentUser.get_loginName();
var form = $("table[class='ms-formtable']"); 
var userField = form.find("input[id$='ClientPeoplePicker_EditorInput']").get(1);
var peoplepicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.PickerObjectFromSubElement(userField);
peoplepicker.AddUserKeys(loginName);
 }

function onFail(sender, args)
{
alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n'+ args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

**[Output] (Tested on My Side)**

[image]

> **Note:** In case you want to set `People` Field (not People1), just set `get(1)` to `get(0)` if you have multiple `People and Picker` field just set `#OrderID`in `get(#OrderID)` based on the order ID of your desired `People and Picker` field on your form

Comment: making this line of code to the following works perfect `var userField = form.find("div[id$='PersoniKonfirmues']").get(0);`